# SharePoint Online (Office 365) - SharePoint Designer not allowing to save file

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I installed SharePoint Designer 2013 and opened a site from our company's Office 365 SharePoint Online. When I try to make any changes in `seattle.master` (or any other html file) and save, it is showing following error message:

```
Server error: Access denied.
```

I setup my own user with full control (owner), so it seems to have enough rights.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling custom script on the site where you are trying to save the file.

You can do this using SPO Shell

```
Set-SPOSite https://contoso.sharepoint.com -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Had this issue a couple days ago and this seemed to fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately Powershell also not allowing me to connect... When I try to cmdlet "Connect-SPOService -Url https://mysite-admin.sharepoint.com -credential myuser@mymydomain.com", it asks me for password, and after that giving me this error message. "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

Comment: Sounds like some sort of authentication issue. You can change the same setting in the SharePoint admin centre but will take around 24hrs to come through.

Comment: Yes it is already done. I posted another question which somewhat related to this if you have any idea about that...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647702/sharepoint-online-office-365-how-to-set-allow-full-control-permission-for-a