# Sharepoint Online (Office 365) - How to set Allow/Full Control permission for 'Add and Customize Pages'

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I could not find a way to enable `Full Control` for the feature `Add and Customize Pages` in `Site Permissions` screen.

I am the administrator of the Site Collection and have created this site myself, but still I could not allow myself to allow this feature. When used `Check Permissions` screen, it is showing `Deny` status (as below):

[image]

My Admin setting for SharePoint has `Custom Script` enabled (as below image):

[image]

I am using SharePoint Online(Office365).

Comment: I have the same issue. So far this is the best answer I found in the internet, but I cannot confirm yet, that it works for 100%. Still testing.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/247284